# Error "-10814" when opening chrome url with webbrowser.open_new()

Tags: python, macos

I run the following commands and receive execution error.

**Here is my code:**

```
import webbrowser
test = "chrome://chrome-urls/"
webbrowser.open_new(test)
```

**Error:**

```
0:37: execution error: An error of type -10814 has occurred. (-10814)
```

What is my mistake? I use Pycharm on MacOs

Comment: Please check your default browser first. Maybe this can work.

Comment: Already checked. Chrome is default browser.

Comment: This command will show you the valid browsers-  `` webbrowser._tryorder ``

Comment: What does PyCharm have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me.

```
import webbrowser
test = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
ff = webbrowser.get('google-chrome')
ff.open(test)
```

But this does not.

```
import webbrowser
test = 'chrome://chrome-urls/'
ff = webbrowser.get('google-chrome')
ff.open(test)
```

Maybe you cannot open this type of urls.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, the key idea is to update browser via code. Maybe you know another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems there isn't much on this error, but what I could find is that `-10814` is a [kLSApplicationNotFoundErr](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/3074489-anonymous/klsapplicationnotfounderr?changes=_1&language=objc). It probably means that the OS launch services can't associate the given URL with a default app to open it, which makes sense since you are trying to open an internal chrome URL. It probably won't throw the same error with standard http/https URLs.